# C# Typebuilder create type with generic parent where the generic param is the type to be created

Tags: c#, .net

I want to dynamically create a type that has the following structure.

```
public abstract class GenericBase<T>
{
}

public class Instantiated : GenericBase<Instantiated>
{

}
```

Using typebuild this seems like a chicken and egg problem. To build the type I have to first set the parent. To set the parent I have to get the type. Is there any way to achieve this?

Here is the code as I current have it

```
var baseType = typeof(GenericBase<>);
var assemblyName = string.Concat(baseType .Namespace, ".", "TestGeneric");

var asmName = new AssemblyName(assemblyName);
var asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName);

var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Instantiated", TypeAttributes.Public);
typeBuilder.SetParent()
var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are overusing generics here. Why do you need `T` in abstract class and why it has to be the same as child class type when you create child class inheriting abstract class.?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2008/06/12/generics-the-self-referencing-generics-pattern/) for some discussion on how this can be useful. The most common use in the Framework itself is `MyType : IEquatable<MyType>`.